# Hudson / SeleniumHQ plugin - How to run the tests on a remote server?

Tags: selenium, hudson, selenium-rc, hudson-plugins

My main problem is about having Hudson perform tests on another machine :

I'm testing a website with Selenium, and the early testing went well. Now is the time to have Hudson test it by itself while I'm busy coding.
I installed the [SeleniumHQ plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Seleniumhq+Plugin) for Hudson and went through the configuration and job setup steps.

Now, a problem remains : the server on which Hudson is installed cannot run the tests, as there is no browser present. It runs on Red Hat. What I'm supposed to do is to have a different machine (Windows Server 2003) run the tests.

Selenium server (the former Selenium RC) works very well on the Windows machine if I do it "by hand", but I just can't figure how to have Hudson delegate his tests ?

My job is using the following configuration, which fails as planned (no browser on this machine) :

Build step / Script :

```
java -jar /var/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*chrome" "http://www.google.com" "/var/hudson/jobs/ProjectTestsHTML/workspace/TestSuiteP22.html" "/var/hudson/jobs/ProjectTestsHTML/workspace/results.html"
```

How can I tweak that to have the other (Windows) server do the selenium part, yet continue to have the reports handled by Hudson ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your tests in a different machine you can use the Hudson Slave concept. The test can be triggered from Master machine but will run in slave machine. You can find step by step details on how to achieve this [here](http://blog.infostretch.com/?p=328)

Comment: Ah, indeed, I did not think about looking into Slave machines. For those having the same problem (running IE Selenium tests with a linux Hudson machine) this is definetly the way to go. The plugin Selenium-Grid can also help to run your tests on several slaves / configurations at a time.  
Thank you for pointing in the right direction, AJ77.